# Scala partial tail recursion

Tags: scala, recursion, stack-overflow, tail-recursion

Because I am defining an interpreter with a lot of variables, I am writing this:

```
type Context = Map[String, Int]
abstract class Expr
case class Let(varname: String, varvalue: Expr, body: Expr) extends Expr
case class Var(name: String) extends Expr
case class Plus(a: Expr, b: Expr) extends Expr
case class Num(i: Int) extends Expr

def eval(expr: Expr)(implicit ctx: Context): Int = expr match {
  case Let(i, e, b) => eval(b)(ctx + (i -> eval(e)))
  case Var(s) => ctx(s)
  case Num(i) => i
  case Plus(a, b) => eval(a) + eval(b)
}
```

For very long expressions this fails because of `StackOverflowException`, for expressions of the type:

```
Let("a", 1, 
Let("b", Plus("a", "a"), 
Let("c", Plus("b", "a"), 
Let("d", 1,  ...  )
```

However, once the value of a variable is defined, I just need to call the evaluator again on the body of the `Let`, it seems to me that it should just do some kind of partial tail-recursion.
How is it possible to achieve partial tail recursion in Scala?

Comment: http://blog.higher-order.com/blog/2015/06/18/easy-performance-wins-with-scalaz/

Comment: Doesn't an expression like `eval(a)+eval(b)` prevent tail recursion? The stack has to be maintained so that the `eval(b)` can be evaluated after the `eval(a)` finishes? Tail recursion is only possible when the returned value is a _single_ call to the recursive function.

Comment: Obviously. This is why I can't have tail-recursion. However, look, in the case I just have a lot of `Let`s, I don't want to keep the stack, I would like to reuse the function like tail-recursion is doing. A kind of partial tail recursion. Tail recurse on the parts that can be tail-recursed, and increase stack size for others.

Comment: Is there any reason you want to avoid trampolining?

Comment: What do you mean by tarmpolining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want some way of getting tail-call optimizations on only some of the branches of `eval`. I don't think this is possible - the most Scala will do is accept a [`@tailrec`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/annotation/tailrec.html) annotation to a method as a whole and fail at compile time if it can't optimize the method into a loop.

However, making this iterative to take advantage of the the tail-call with the `Let` is pretty straight forward:

```
def eval(expr: Expr, ctx: Context): Int = {

  // The expression/context pair we try to reduce at every loop iteration
  var exprM = expr;
  var ctxM = ctx;

  while (true) {
    expr match {
      case Var(s) => return ctxM(s)
      case Num(i) => return i
      case Plus(a, b) => return eval(a,ctxM) + eval(b,ctxM)
      case Let(i, e, b) => {
        ctxM += i -> eval(e,ctxM). // Update ctxM
        exprM = b                  // Update exprM
      }
    }
  }
  return 0; // unreachable, but Scala complains otherwise I'm not returning 'Int'
}
```

Note this won't solve the stack overflows due to long chains of `Plus`s - there really isn't much we can do with those because the recursive calls are not in tail position.

There was a time I thought Scala would make some `@tailcall` annotation to deal with this sort of thing, but I am not sure there is that much interest in such things anymore.

Comment: It looks like your solution is the best alternative. Note that you can just write `exprM = expr match { .... case Let(i, e, b) => ctxM += i -> eval(e, ctxM); b }` if you want to avoid assigning exprM multiple times. A `return` statement short-circuits the assignments in any case.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using `return` in scala. In this scenario you could use a flag for the while control.
e.g.

```
var result = Option.empty[Int]
while (result.isEmpty) {
  ...
  result = ctxM(s)
  ...
}
result
```

There are also other (IMO better) ways to go about this. For example https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/freemonad.html